# Finding and graphing the cube roots of $1 + i$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

The question asks to find the indicated roots and graph them in the complex plane.
The cube roots of $1 + i$

Thus, my answer is:
\begin{align*}
\omega_0 & = 2^{1/6}[\cos(\pi/12)+i\sin(\pi/12)]\\
\omega_1 & = 2^{1/6}[\cos(7\pi/12)+i\sin(7\pi/12)]\\
\omega_2 & = 2^{1/6}[\cos(13\pi/12)+i\sin(13\pi/12)]
\end{align*}

and the graph I choose is attached below
However, it would tell me that the answer of $\omega_0$ is right, whilst the others are wrong and I am not sure if the graph chose is right or wrong

What is the correct graph for this solution

[choose the right graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2sGO.png)

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Hint : $1+i = \sqrt{2}e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown the question is stated above. to find the indicated roots of the cube root of 1+i and graph it

Comment: Your graph can't be right since all cube roots of $1+i$ have modulus $\sqrt{2}$

Comment: $W_0$ is correct, but then you're adding $\pi/2$ to the argument, where you should be adding $2\pi/3$.

Comment: @saulspatz wait I am confused now, so for W1 it should be 2pi/3 instead of 7pi/12? and for W2 it should be 9pi/2?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: No, you want to multiply by the cube roots of 1.  That is, by $e^{i2\pi/3}$ and  $e^{i4\pi/3}.$  That is, you add $2\pi/3$ to the argument twice.  In $W_0$ the argument is $\pi/12$ so in $W_1$ it's $9\pi/12=3\pi/4.$

Comment: It has magnitude $(\sqrt2)^ \frac13 $ and angle $ \frac13\cdot \pi/4$ So first choice $\omega_0$ is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Wir like to solve $z^3=1+i$ for $z\in\mathbb C$. We can do it using the polar coordinates, so
$$
z^3=1+i=\sqrt{2}e^{\frac14\pi i}=\sqrt{2}e^{\frac14\pi i+2k\pi i}\text{ for all }k\in\mathbb Z.
$$
We get
$$
z=2^{\frac16}e^{\frac1{12}\pi i+\frac23k\pi i}\text{ for all }k\in\mathbb Z.
$$
Because the exponential function is periodic to $2\pi i$, we get
\begin{align*}
z_0=&2^{\frac16}e^{\frac1{12}\pi i}=2^{\frac16}\left(\cos\left(\frac1{12}\pi\right)+i\sin\left(\frac1{12}\pi\right)\right),\\
z_1=&2^{\frac16}e^{\frac1{12}\pi i+\frac23\pi i}=2^{\frac16}e^{\frac{3}{4}\pi i}=2^{\frac16}\left(\cos\left(\frac34\pi\right)+i\sin\left(\frac34\pi\right)\right),\\
z_2=&2^{\frac16}e^{\frac1{12}\pi i+\frac23\cdot 2\pi i}=2^{\frac16}e^{\frac{17}{12}\pi}=2^{\frac16}\left(\cos\left(\frac{17}{12}\pi\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{17}{12}\pi\right)\right).
\end{align*}

Why are your $w_1$ and $w_2$ wrong? You can simply compute:
$$
w_1^3 =\left(2^{\frac16}e^{\frac7{12}\pi i}\right)^3=\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{21}{12}\pi i}=\sqrt{2}e^{\frac74\pi i}=1-i
$$
and
$$
w_2^3=\left(2^{\frac16}e^{\frac{13}{12}\pi i}\right)^3=\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{39}{12}\pi i}=\sqrt{2}e^{\frac54\pi i}=-1-i.
$$

Comment: I attached two options of graphs, would u mind telling me which graph suits the solution because I could not figure it out. Thank you for the detailed explanation

Comment: The left one is wrong. So have to consider that $2^{\frac16}\approx  1.12$, so the three points have to be on the sphere around $0$ with radius $2^{\frac16}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $$1+i= \sqrt 2 e^{i\pi /4}= \sqrt 2 e^{i( 2\pi + \pi /4)}= \sqrt 2 e^{i(4\pi+\pi /4)}$$

Therefore

$$ x^3 = 1+i \implies x_1= 2^{1/6} e^{i\pi /12} ; x_2= 2^{1/6} e^{i 9\pi /12} ; x_3= 2^{1/6} e^{i 17\pi /12}$$

Comment: will it be correct if I wrote it in the form of cosine and sine? or I have to convert it to the value of e

Comment: thank you for the explanation

Comment: @Amy You are welcome. :). And both the representations are correct.

Comment: can you help me choose which graph is the correct from the attachment I have included, whatever I choose would appear wrong and I am struggling to figure out which graph suits the solution

Comment: @Amy  [Follow this link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2Bi)%5E(1%2F3)) here you'll get complete analysis of cube roots of $1+i$. Scroll down to the end, and you'll see all the three cube roots plotted.